# AngularJs Prerender

Tags: javascript, angularjs

PREFACE: I have an AngularJS application with a controller. In the view of this controller I fill a `ng-repeat` with a list using a JSON object. If I have a slow device such as a phone, the render can be so slow that I can view an empty page for a while before the content arrives some seconds later.

QUESTION: How can I show a pre-load while I wait for the render? Is there some trick or event I can bind to to show a "Waiting" row then hide this row and show the list rendered (when complete).

Thanks all.

P.S. Without jQuery and friends, AngularJS only.

Comment: hey, my example below might have a downvote, but it is a working example. and is applicable not only to ng-repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **ng-cloak**
plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lgNSdTrMMexHykUBIqnT?p=preview

**this example is very much applicable and is NOT LIMITED to ng-repeat, if you download this be reasonable -- put a comment please**

## NOTE: this Genius example is working, put a comment please if you will downvote it

althought the example uses manual bootstrapping, the behavior is the same. it just use manual bootstrap to demonstrate what it would look like if angularjs is not done bootstrapping yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script>

      function jsBootStrap() {
        console.log('bootstrapping');
        angular.bootstrap(document);
      }

      angular.module("ng").run(function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.DisplayMyData = "AngularJS Loves Noypi";
      });

    </script>

    <style>
      .preview{
        display:none;  
      }
      .ng-cloak.preview {
        color:blue;
        display:block!important;
      }       
      .ng-cloak.realview {
        display:none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="ng-cloak preview">
      I was shown before AngularJS. <br/>
      Credits <u>ngtutorial.com/learn/bootstrap</u>.
    </div> 
    <div class="ng-cloak realview">
        <span ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]">
            {{$index}} = {{DisplayMyData}}<br/>
        </span><br/>
    </div>


    <button onclick="jsBootStrap()">bootstrap document</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I apologise, Noypi, I was the downvoter. It was because I initially felt you had not understood the OP's question, and I questioned the need to manually bootstrap Angular. However, on reflection, I acknowledge that for the OP's specific question, if this was just a single page where you want to show content until AngularJS has loaded and fully rendered the content, then your solution works. I'm not sure how well it would work if this was just one page in a whole SPA where AngularJS is already bootstrapped, however. Would it work then?

Comment: it is more flexible and easy to optimize than using ng-app; think of loading a lot of dependencies for big SPAs -- see, angular-loader.

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
<p ng-show="list.length<1">Waiting...</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

**show loading until data is not load**

```
<p ng-hide="list.length">Loading... or here can set a loading image path in img tag</p>
```

**when json data find it will show**

```
<p ng-show="list.length">
<div ng-repeat="list">// your json data in list
</div>
</p>
```

Comment: Just wanted to tell you, that you are doing HTML incest puting a DIV inside a P.